# Observable from Behavior Subject is not working properly

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am working on an Angular app where I am trying to use a service with a behavior subject that is getting updates from firestore. I am trying to make a function that will return an observable with just the selected item.  My issue is that when I subscribe to the observable created from the behavior subject, the observable is emiting an empty array and is not firing again when data changes.

My service looks like this

```
export class TripService {

    constructor(private db: AngularFirestore, private store: Store<fromRoot.State>) { }

    private tripSource = new BehaviorSubject([])
    public trips$: Observable<any> = this.tripSource.asObservable()

    updateTrips() {
        return this.db.collection('trips', ref => ref.where('agentId', '==', authState.uid).valueChanges({ idField: 'id' })).pipe(
    tap((trips) => this.tripSource.next(trips))
    )
    }

    getSelectedTrip() {
        return this.store.select(fromRoot.getTripId).pipe( //using ngrx to get selected trip
            filter((tripId: any) => !!tripId),
            switchMap(tripId => this.trips$.pipe(
                map((trips: Trip[]) => trips.filter(trip => trip.id === tripId)[0])
            ))
        )
    }
}
```

In my app.component I am calling the updateTrips function to get the initial data and whenever data changes in firestore, it logs out the new trips to the console

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.store.dispatch(fromAuthActions.loadUser());
    this.tripService.updateActiveAgentTrips().subscribe(trips => console.log('trips are:', trips));  //this logs the trips!
    this.clientService.getAgentClients().subscribe()
    this.destinationService.updateDestinations().subscribe();
}
```

My item component ngOninit looks like this

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.tripService.getSelectedTrip().pipe(
        tap((trip: Trip) => this.trip = trip)
    .subscribe(trip => console.log(trip))  //logs: [] and doesn't emit again
}
```

Is there a reason the observable is emiting in the app.component but not in the trip.component when the data changes in firestore?

Comment: can you provide stackblitz?

Comment: sample minimal demo will help. You can mock the firestore response. On a side note - You probably don't want to use .next in tap. Tap is mainly there for side affects. You can directly map over your tripSource stream